# Can't delete AWS RDS Global database. Deletion protection option missing

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, cluster-computing, global

Trying to delete a Global RDS database (Postgres 11.9).
I deleted all the instances, and region clusters.
For this Global database cluster, getting error "Cannot delete protected Global Cluster ***********, please disable deletion protection and try again."

When I go to Modify, there is no deletion protection option to uncheck, like there is for a regular cluster.

I am trying to do this via AWS Console.

Any advices?
Thanks.

Comment: Try with [this](https://repost.aws/questions/QU2o4hJ6ZFQ0qFzlHgAS5DXg/how-to-disable-deletion-protection#ANC4mG7xDcSNKN3R6TXZdlug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update.
After contacting AWS, their support suggested that for Global Database Clusters, deletion protection has to be disabled using the AWS CLI. Can't do it from the AWS Console.
This is the syntax I used to disable deletion protection:

```
aws rds modify-global-cluster --global-cluster-identifier <cluster identifier> --no-deletion-protection
```

Then I deleted the cluster from the console.